# replace &lt;/p&gt from the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame column description. I want to remove the text "<p> "& "<br>" from DataFrame column and just keep the text.

```
     Description
     "&lt;p&gt;ID being used for RPA testing&lt;/p&gt;"
     "This NUID is used for User Acceptance Testing of the RPA solutions for mainframe provisioning (ACF2 NP10 and all IDMS lower environments)&lt;br&gt;"
     &lt;p>ID being used for RPA testing&lt;/p>
     This NUID is used for User Acceptance Testing of the RPA solutions for mainframe provisioning (ACF2 NP10 and all IDMS lower environments)&lt;br>
```

Expected Output

```
        Description
      ID being used for RPA testing
      This NUID is used for User Acceptance Testing of the RPA solutions for mainframe provisioning (ACF2 NP10 and all IDMS lower environments)
      ID being used for RPA testing
     This NUID is used for User Acceptance Testing of the RPA solutions for mainframe provisioning (ACF2 NP10 and all IDMS lower environments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is not complicated, you can use regex to remove anything between `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Description": [
        "&lt;p&gt;ID being used for RPA testing&lt;/p&gt;",
        "This NUID is used for User Acceptance Testing of the RPA solutions for mainframe provisioning (ACF2 NP10 and all IDMS lower environments)&lt;br&gt;"
    ]
})

pattern = re.compile('&lt;.+?(&gt;|>)')
df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.replace(pattern, "")
```

For more complex requirements, you will have to dive into a proper HTML parser like BeautifulSoup to extract the plain text.

Comment: Can I use multiple values for patterns ? I have "&lt;br>","&lt;/p>"

Comment: Yes you can, but your new pattern is adding to the complexity. What is your expected output from the new example?

Comment: Updated the pattern!